# How to determine whether given nonlinear equation system cannot be solved analytically?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I am currently studying nonlinear equations that require numerical analysis methods to solve them. But I could not understand why can't I solve some equations analytically?

For example: x^2 + 4y^2 - 16 = 0 and x(y^2) - 3 = 0

How can I determine that this equation system cannot be solved analytically before using numerical analysis methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve the equation even algebraically. The solution is given by
$$
x=\frac{1}{3}(4y^2( 4 - y^2)),
$$
where $y$ satisfies the equation
$$
4y^6 - 16y^4 + 9=0.
$$
This is a cubic equation in $z=y^2$, where we have a formula. We obtain four real solutions and two complex ones.